# elementary os is freezing

Tags: appcenter, drivers, nvidia, hardware

I change my pc's videocard after some days it's start freezing/ and i restarting every time. I'm downloading nvidia drivers from app center/ have a 2 download I'm downloading both but when I restart my pc one of both non installing and when I open the second program it's freezing